# Which Datasources are supported for streaming data processing in GCP Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

After reading alot about dataflow, i could find only PubSub & bigquery as datasources which support streaming data processing in GCP dataflow.

Which are some other datasources supported?

Can i do all the streaming tasks using dataflow those are possible using other ETL tools like Spark or Kafka?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Beam provides extensible support to build IO for any type of stream source. There are implementations for [Kafka](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/package-summary.html), Kinesis, MQTT in the SDK.

Given the separation of transport, format and downstream bundling architecture in Beam you should be able to interact with any type of stream source as long as the underlying format is serializable.

Comment: Thanks Eric Schmidt,  Are this all transformations possible with Python sdk?

Comment: Historically, Python only had support for PubSub, but there is an ongoing effort to wrap all Java connectors using the new cross language capabilities (see https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/connectors-multi-sdk/), for example Kafka is supported in the latest release: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/external/kafka.py . Python also provides support for the full model of transformations (ParDo, windowing, grouping, state and timers, etc.).